# AWS StepFunctions sum() function returns error about not finding path

Tags: amazon-web-services, jsonpath, aws-step-functions

I have a StepFunction with input:

```json
{
  "Jobs": [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0]
}
```

and I want the sum of the values in this array. According to the [Json-Path docs](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) there should exist a `.sum()` function for this. When I try it [here](http://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/) it even works. So I defined the following Pass state:

```json
"Sum Jobs": {
  "Type": "Pass",
  "Parameters": {
   "Jobs.$": "$.Jobs.sum()"
  }
},
```

Nevertheless executions fail with:

```
"An error occurred while executing the state 'Sum Jobs' (entered at the event id #249). The JSONPath '$.Jobs.sum()' specified for the field 'Jobs.$' could not be found in the input '{\"Jobs\":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0]}'"
```

Comment: Functions such as length() and sum() aren't supported. See here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-paths.html

Answer (score 1):

You will need a Lambda Task for this. Step Functions' [intrinsic functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions.html) (= operations accessible outside of tasks), do not include any math or array manipulation operations.